# Remove row in Query if a column has its unique identifier

Tags: sql

In a table in our database, I have an identifier(PK) and then another column called ParentId. We have items that each get their own unique identifier. If that item is altered after arrival, it gets a new identifier and then in the ParentId column, it references the original identifier prior to alteration. I am trying to write a query that if ParentId is not null, then remove the row with an identifier that equals that of the ParentId. Below is an example table of what I am trying to explain.

[image]

I want to keep the green row, but because the value in the parentId for the green row matches the Identifier in the yellow row, I want to not include the yellow row in the query.

Comment: You could left join the table to itself on parent id = identifier and use where ‘columnfromjoin’ IS NOT NULL

Comment: Thanks. I will give that a try

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the parents out with a `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM YourTable t2
    WHERE t2.ParentId = t.Identifier
);
```

Or a `NOT IN`

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE Identifier NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ParentId FROM YourTable);
```